# How to get overloaded constructors of a class through WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, constructor, constructor-overloading

How can I get the overloaded constructors on my classes passed on to the WCF client/consumer?

Basically, WCF thinks there is only the default, no argument/empty constructor for my B class. How can I enable the client to call the overloaded constructors?

```
public class A
{
    public string MyField { get; set; }

}

public class B : A
{
    public List<C> MyList { get; set; }

    // when called on the WCF client side, MyList is null (so this constructor is not being called)
    public B()
    {
        MyList = new List<C>();
    }

    // not available on WCF client side
    public B(A a) : this()
    {
        base.MyField = a.MyField;
    }

    // not available on WCF client side
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is a class only construct that a wcf client is not aware of. The boundaries are different.

The client just knows about a proxy class. And the WCF infrastructure creates the proxy class with the default constructors. Independent of the constructors at the server side, because they don't mean anything from the WCF perspective.

Only Service Contracts, Operation COntracts and Data Contracts matter.

if you want additional functionality in your proxy class, you can always add a partial class with the same name on your client side and add code to it. (overloaded constructors etc.) be aware that the server doesn't really care about this.

Comment: Ok, great info. How do suggest I get this functionality to my client? The overloaded constructors that is.

Comment: typically WCF clients will generate a Reference.cs file with partial class. you can add another CS file (to not disturb the original autogenerated reference.cs file) and your constructors there.

Comment: I also have a method (see updated code). Are there any annotations I can add to the class to get access to my method "DoSomething()" on the client?

Comment: You can mark DoSomething with the OperationContract attribute to expose it as a web method for wcf clients. Assuming the container class is the service class.

Comment: Lindsay, it looks like you want some specific things to happen (values initialized etc.) on the server when a client wcf request is made. Can you articulate it in altogether?